# Extract Part of Title Tag

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to extract part of the title tag using Javascript? Like, extract all text in the title tag up to a dash character, and not text after the dash character.

**Example**
`<title>Extract this text-But not text after the dash</title>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.title.split('-')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = document.title;
var dashIdx = title.indexOf("-");
var part = title.substring(0, dashIdx);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title.substring(0, document.title.indexOf('-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dTt = document.title;
dTt.substring(0, dTt.indexOf('-'));
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods